# mysqli_query database selection error

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, mysqli

Im trying to select text from a database but only the text that was posted by certain usernames. Basically I need someone to look at this PHP and MySQL code and tell me what they see is wrong with it. I hope I have given enough info. Also, I get this erro: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in... Thanks! Here is the code:

```
$followed = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT followed FROM follows WHERE follower = '$username'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($followed)){

    echo $row['followed']."<br>";
    $followed = $row['followed'];

    $random = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT text FROM post WHERE user = '$followed'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($random)){
        echo "<ul><li id = 'stream-post'>";
        echo $row['text'];
        echo "</li></ul>";
        $user = $row['user'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Google the error message and let us know what you think it might be.

Comment: Please use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in the code is that `$followed` is the variable holding the SQL result. And after the first fetch, that gets overwritten with a string value. The next time through the loop, `$followed` is no longer a reference to the result set returned by the query.

There's also attempt to retrieve key `'user'` from the array `$row`, and the key does not exist in the array.

Also, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, and there is no checking whether the return from a query is successful or not. We'd prefer to see **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**, but at a minimum, you should be calling the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function on "unsafe" values, and include the return from the function in the SQL text.

---

Here's an example of the pattern I prefer to follow

```
# set the SQL text to a variable
$sql = "SELECT followed FROM follows WHERE follower = '" 
     . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username) . "' ORDER BY 1"; 
# for debugging
#echo "SQL=" . $sql; 

# execute the query
$sth = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

# check if query was successful, and handle somehow if not
if (!$sth) {
    die mysqli_error($con);
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sth)) {
    $followed = $row['followed'];
    echo htmlspecialchars($followed) ."<br>";

    # set SQL text 
    $sql2 = "SELECT text FROM post WHERE user = '"
          . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $followed) . "' ORDER BY 1";
    # for debugging
    #echo "SQL=" . $sql2;

    # execute the query
    $sth2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);

    # check if query execution was successful, handle if not
    if (!$sth2) {
       die mysqli_error($con);
    }

    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sth2)) {
        $text = $row2['text'];

        echo "<ul><li id = 'stream-post'>" . htmlspecialchars($text) . "</li></ul>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as a hint: the second loop assigns the result to `row` which already holds the row from the first query. Use a different variable name:

```
    ...
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($followed)){

    echo $row['followed']."<br>";
    $followed = $row['followed'];

    $random = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT text FROM post WHERE user = '$followed'");

    while($subrow = mysqli_fetch_array($random)){
        echo "<ul><li id = 'stream-post'>";
        echo $subrow['text'];
        ....
```

second: column `user`is not part of either SELECT (`... $user = $row['user'];`)

I assume, it's the second query:

```
     "SELECT user, text FROM post WHERE user = '$followed'"
```

Comment: It's not necessarily wrong to reuse `$row`. OP already grabbed the column values returned into the array by the fetch. A bigger issue is attempting to retrieve array key `'user'` when that key is not in the array. The example code posted here is subject to SQL Injection, just like the OP code is.

Comment: @spencer7593 regarding the two `row`'s: When the code stays as it is, you might be right. If it will be altered / evolved, these kind of things are reason for some night shift with debugging ...

Comment: The real problem is the reuse of `$followed`. The first time through the loop, that gets overwritten. The second fetch is trying to fetch from a string, rather than the resultset.  I prefer to use a variable name like `$sth` (statement handle) or `$stmt` for the resultset. (A throwback to my earlier Perl DBI days).

Comment: Thanks Axel, the duplicated $follows was the problem.